# Android: A Toast when OutComing call

Tags: android, call, broadcastreceiver

i'm trying this code found on internet...it should show a toast for OutComing call event using a BroadcastReceiver but on my htc tattoo with Android 1.6 it doesn't works (it don't show any toast)

```
public class HFBroadcastOutComingRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Toast.makeText(context, "Phone Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     if(null == bundle)
           return;
     String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
     String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nOutgoing number: " + phonenumber;
        Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Naturally i've registered the BroadcastReceiver on my Manifest as:

```
  <receiver android:name=".HFBroadcastIncomingRecevier">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

and with this permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: From what I see, there are missing parts of my question, so this is the receiver in manifest:
<receiver android:name=".HFBroadcastIncomingRecevier">
   <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

And this are the permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: edited. they are now here. Don't forget to use curly braces icon above the edit field to improve formatting of your code.

Comment: did you call registerreceiver()?

Answer (score 0):

Change intent filter to ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

```
<receiver android:name=".YourClassName" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And if this doesnt work also implement an intent filter in your onReceive

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String mAction = intent.getAction();
    if(!mAction.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        return;
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

This is for incoming msg change it accordingly and an [example here](http://www.krvarma.com/posts/android/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)

Comment: Yes it was my original source